# If the where clauses is not match ,Want to return all data with linq

Tags: linq

I have to filter data with startdate and enddate.IF there is no startdate and enddate,Want to return all data, if start date and end date is not null,want to return data between start date and end date with linq

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to create an extension method for this.

If you are not familiar with extension methods, see [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

If you will be using it just for this class, make an extension method for this class only. If you plan to use it for generic filtering on "value between to other values" (or just for fun, as an exercise) make a generic method.

> IF there is no startdate and enddate, Want to return all data, if start date and end date is not null,want to return data between start date and end date

This literally says: return all date if start date == null AND end date ==  null. Otherwise: return data between start date and end date.

Requirement problem: if start date equals null, and end date not is null, how to return data between start date and end date?

Alas, you forgot to mention the class that has the Dates, so let's assume you have a query for Students with a BirthDate:

```
public static IQueryable<Student> WherBirthDateBetween(
    this IQueryable<Student> students,
    DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate)
{
    if (startDate == null)
    {
        if (endDate == null)
            // startDate AND endDate == null: no filtering
            return persons;
        else
             // startDate == null; endDate != null
             // requirement problem. Let's assume you want all Students <= endDate
             return students.Where(student => student .BirthDay <= endDate.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        if (endDate == null)
            // startDate != null; endDate == null
            // requirement problem. Let's assume you want all students >= startDate
            return students.Where(student => student .BirthDay >= startDate.Value);
        else
            // startDate != null; endDate != null, return where date betweeen:
            return students.Where(student => person.BirthDay >= startDate.Value
                                          && student.BirthDay <= endDate.Value);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
IQueryable<Student> students = ...
DateTime? startDate = ...
DateTime? endDate = ...

var filteredStudents = students.WhereBirthdayBetween(startDate, endDate)
                               .ToList();
```

Note, because you procedure is executed before ToList() is called, WhereBirthdayBetween is executed only once, even if there are thousand Students. startDate and endDate are evaluated only once. The Expression in the IQueryable is changed only once